# Generalization of Symmetric Group: $S_n$ to ${\bf S'}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, exact-sequence, group-extensions

We know the symmetric group is defined over any set is the group whose elements are all the bijections from the set to itself.

S$_n$ is defined over a finite set of $n$ symbols consists of the permutation operations that can be performed on the $n$ symbols.

Suppose these $n$ symbols are:

$$(1,2,3,\dots,n)$$

other than any of the permutation of order $n!$.

Let us also allow an additional $\pm$ sign as a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ cyclic group on each symbols

$$\pm 1,\pm 2, \pm 3,\dots,\pm n$$

We allow all operations including the permutation and the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ cyclic group on each symbol.

Let us call this the generalized symmetric group ${\bf S'}_n$, which has an order

$$(2^n) n!$$

So a generic group element can be represented by

$$
(1,2,3,\dots,n) \to (2,-3,\dots,-(n-k),k)
$$
or anything now you can imagine.

> Question 1: How is this group related to another more familiar group, say a group extension from $S_n$?

A partial answer* For $n=2$, we have the order-2 group 
$$S_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$ and the order-8 group
$${\bf S'}_2=D_8$$
So the answer I look for $n=2$ is that, the 
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to {\bf S'}_2=D_8 \to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2 \to  0
$$
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to {\bf S'}_2=D_8 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to  0
$$ 
$$
0 \to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2 \to {\bf S'}_2=D_8 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to  0
$$ 
There are several $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ above as quotient group or normal subgroup of ${\bf S'}_2=D_8$,

> but none of normal subgroup is directly the
>   $S_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Yes or no? But we have
>   $$
> 0 \to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2 \to {\bf S'}_2=D_8 \to {S}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to  0
> $$ 
>   for a good choice of a normal subgroup $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.

---

> Question 2:  Do we have a similar structure for
>   $$
> 0 \to ? \to {\bf S'}_n \to ? \to  0
> $$
>   Can we find $S_n$ sitting somewhere in ${\bf S'}_n$ related to quotient group or normal subgroup of  ${\bf S'}_n$?

Maybe also be related: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Generalized_symmetric_group

Comment: Your definition is quite unclear ("generic" is senseless, maybe you just mean one example), but I guess you mean the group of permutations $s$ of $\{-n,\dots,n-1,n\}$ such that $s(-k)=-s(k)$ for all $k$. It has order $2^nn!$ and is a semidirect product $(Z/2Z)^n\rtimes S_n$. This is the well-known [hyperoctahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group).

Comment: great, this may be almost what I need. However, I want to know more how $S_n$ can sit inside this group

Comment: As YCor said, the hyperoctahedral group is a semidirect product of an elementary abelian $2$-group and $S_n$. So $S_n$ is both a subgroup and a quotient. It's easy to show that it is not (isomorphic to) a normal subgroup for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: $S_n$ sits as the stabilizer of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: it is not (isomorphic to) a normal subgroup for $n=2$, if we be specific about which $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Sorry but what you said is meaningless. The whole point of saying "isomorphic to" is to say that we don't care "which". In any case, you should clarify if what's written so far is enough to answer your questions and, if not, be a bit clearer about what you want.

Comment: sorry, I am an engineer, I will try to be precise. But the normal subgroup of ′$_2$ cannot be  $_2$. Do you agree?

Comment: @verret,

the normal subgroup of ′$_2$ cannot be $_2$.

the normal subgroup of ′$_n$ cannot be $_n$.

Comment: Yes, sure, but $S'_2$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $S_2$.